# Windows 7 Password sharing OFF

Tags: windows-7, windows, passwords, file-sharing

I try to access my computer without password protected .it popup me `username/password` when i try to access my computer to another computer in the same `LAN`.

i try to `OFF` the `Password Protected Sharing Sector`, but it again pop me the `username/password` screen.

How to remove password proctected sharing?

**NOTE: i am using Windows 7 Professional**

Comment: Have you joined both computers to the same HomeGroup?

Comment: @Ramhound yes, both computer are on same HomeGroup.